# Option filter in select box in React

Tags: reactjs, api, html-select

I have a select box that I need to fill with 6 options. For example,

```
<select
                  id="watchSize"
                  className="form-select"
                  aria-label="Watch Size"
                >
                  <option selected>{post.size}</option>
                  <option>Normal</option>
                  <option>Big</option>
                  <option>Small</option>
                </select>
```

As you see, there are 3 different kinds of sizes in the select box. So I defined these sizes hardcoded but I am taking the specific size of the watch from API which is coming like {post.size}. So, what I want to do is if {post.size} is Small, I don't want to show Small in the options and the value should be {post.size} in this case.
I hope I am clear.
Is there any way that I can do it?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks...

Comment: In my opinion, in terms of friendly UX, I wouldn't hide the `Small` option, it's still valid and it's actually the selected value, if you want to have that value selected depending on api value use `defaultValue` prop on `select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Here I took an array of sizes and placing the selected  size at the front of the array and Set is taking unique items keeping the order. Then map function is returning all the jsx.

```
<select
    id="watchSize"
    className="form-select"
    aria-label="Watch Size"
    >
    {[...new Set([post.size, "Normal", "Big", "Small"])].map(i => <option selected={i===post.size}>{i}</option>)}
</select>
```

Comment: I can try this one but I am getting something like this: '...' expected.ts(1005)
(parameter) idx: number

Comment: ok, may be `'selected'` to be wrapped in quotes

Comment: but idx is giving the problem. Since I couldny get what you mean with idx I couldnt understand actually

Comment: in `map` function idx or the second parameter carries index. It should not give any error.

Comment: it is giving Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

Comment: you wrappend selected in quotes? like `'selected'`

Comment: Yes I did but idx shows the error actually

Comment: Apperantly ... is necessary in front of the i so it should be like this <option {...i===post.size ? 'selected' : undefined}>{i}</option> But I couldnt understand why to be honest